# My edit rejected in favor of the poor

Tags: support, rejected-edits

User SilentGhost has just stolen two of my suggested edits. [One](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1012591). [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1012589). It was simple update of invalid link. One of edits was here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641616/python-and-web-development . I see in the history of reviews:

> SilentGhost reviewed this 25 mins ago: Edit
>   Community ♦ reviewed this 25 mins ago: Reject
>   Pedro Romano reviewed this 26 mins ago: Approve

I wouldn't mind if his edit was better than mine, but it's even worse:

Old invalid link was http://wsgi.org/wsgi/
My link was: http://wsgi.org
His link is: http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Can somebody explain what's going on? Has he received reputation for this?

Comment: SilentGhost has 52.4k reputation and therefore no longer gets reputation for editing.

Comment: Also, what is 'worse' about the link? That's where a user *ends up* when going to your link, via redirection. I think the edit is (marginally) better.

Comment: Andrew Barber, My link is more stable. What do you prefer no redirection or stability of the link?

Comment: @AndrewBarber: If it were just a basic redirection, then that would make sense. But this redirection adds a **language identifier** to the URL, which means anyone who clicks it will always go to the English version of the site. That's worse.

Comment: @animuson That's a good point. Although I would note that you can replace `en` with anything in the resulting URL, and you still get an English version. (Not sure that's relevant for the edit, though)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This simply occurred because SilentGhost has chosen the <kbd>Improve</kbd> option for edits, but then decided that your original edit was unhelpful. His rejection made it through immediately since the three-reviewers limit is forced to be reached if a reviewer edits the post in their own way. This person no longer gains reputation and therefore gains nothing.

While the link is indeed marginally better in your case, IMHO this is a small problem and you shouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: Now it's clear. Thank you.

Comment: I would call that rejection just being ignorant. Since when is the language-specific version of a link ever *better*? I remember people made a huge fuss a while back over removing all the language-specific links from the PHP tag wiki and other wikis...

Comment: except that the language happens to :en and perhaps a few people are indeed ignorant of that